# Is `limited to viewing` correct in this context? Your account is `limited to` viewing only the first 100 pictures

Tags: infinitives

As the title says, is `limited to` correct in that context?

> Let's say for instance that Facebook offers free and paid account and Facebook only allows free account to view the first 100 pictures of your friend. When a user tries to view more than 100 pictures, then Facebook will say `Your account is limited to viewing the first 100 pictures`.

If that is correct, can anyone point me to an English rule that allows "past tense" + "to" + "verb-ing"? Also, I do not know what kind of verb is "limited to viewing" or what is it called in English.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Consider **viewing the first 100 pictures** as one single entity. Call it **object**. Here, in your example, this entity is the object of the verb **limited**. 
So the sentence becomes "your account is limited to **object**. "

Even if we consider the question title, it is correct in itself because the word **viewing** is a gerund, which can act either as a subject or object.

Comment: Hi @vickyace, sorry, in `limited to object`, could you please explain what `limited to` means?

Comment: Here, "limit" is used to describe an action that restricts or confines something. In your example it confines the number of photos you can view.